# Find Italics in a named range excel 2010 vba then add values to a variable and output to form control

Tags: excel, vba, loops, italic

I am trying to search each cell individually in a named range and find each cell that has italic font.  If the font is italic then I would like to add that cell's number to a variable so I can get a total.

Any help is much appreciated.

Justin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the `.Font.Italic` property. Test the following. Modify accordingly.

```
Sub AddItalicizedNums()
    Dim TargetRng As Range, Cell As Range
    Dim SumOfItalics
    Set TargetRng = Range("OneToTwenty")
    SumOfItalics = 0
    For Each Cell In TargetRng
        If Cell.Font.Italic = True Then
            SumOfItalics = SumOfItalics + Cell.Value
        End If
    Next Cell
    MsgBox SumOfItalics
End Sub
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

My named range is `OneToTwenty` and I italicized (and boldfaced) all even numbers in it. The sum is showing correctly, as shown in the message box.

Let us know if this helps.

Comment: I haven't even tried your code but just looking at it this is exactly what I am looking for!!!!!!!  Thank you very much for not only the advice but a viable solution!!!

Comment: @ndjustin20: No worries. Kindly mark the answer as accepted if this helped you. This is how we say thanks in SO. Good luck!